# Drupal 7. How I change content in custom block via template.php?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I created simple block in admin page with HTML content and now I need to modify this content via template.php. What need for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your .tpl file based on your block ID.

For example:

If you've created block with an ID

`block-block-1`

then the template name should be

```
block--block--1.tpl.php
```

Main steps:

- Identify your block ID
- Go on your theme folder and find folder with template files
- Copy block.tpl.php in your theme's templates folder and rename it into name based on block's ID (block--block--1.tpl.php in this case)
- Flush all caches

**NOTE**:
When you're editing your custom block you can see in URL the path with block's delta. It will be something like

```
/admin/structure/block/manage/block/5/configure
```

For this URL, you should use block--block--5.tpl.php. The number 5 is block's delta in this case. You can also view the source of the page where your block appears (or use Firebug to inspect) and look for the ID given to the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7.x) to alter the content of a block inside `template.php`. This way, you can add logic to decide the content.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter().
 *
 * It is better to get the module and delta for block using dpm($block) by
 * implementing hook_block_view_alter() before.
 */
function mytheme_block_view_block_1_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if (some_criteria_met_on_which_you_wanted_to_change_content) {
    $data['content'] = t('This is how I altered the content of the block-1 inside template.php.');
  }
}
```

[image]

In the above picture, you can see **module = block** and **delta = 1**. Therefore, the hook is `mytheme_block_view_block_1_alter()`.

**Note:**

- MODULE - The name of the module that defined the block.
- DELTA - The unique identifier for the block within that module, as defined in hook_block_info().

for queries, use comments.